# Bulk Load in SQL Server failed to load float values

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy, mssql-jdbc

I have to transfer data from one database server to a SQL Server. I'm using `SQLServerBulkCopy` to do that:

```
// connection1 is with the source system and
// connection2 is with the destination SQL Server
Statement statement = connnection1.createStatement();

ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("select * from db.table");

SQLServerBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SQLServerBulkCopy(connection2);
bulkCopy.setDestinationTableName("tableName");
bulkCopy.writeToServer(resultSet);
```

I'm getting following error while doing that:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Data type float is not supported in bulk copy.
>
> at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:226)
>   at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.getDestTypeFromSrcType(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1443)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.createInsertBulkCommand(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1464)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.sendBulkCopyCommand(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1611)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.doInsertBulk(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1553)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.access$200(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:63)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy$1InsertBulk.doExecute(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:705)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7240)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2869)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.sendBulkLoadBCP(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:733)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:1669)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeResultSet(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:641)
>       at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerBulkCopy.writeToServer(SQLServerBulkCopy.java:579)

Is there anyway to get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try creating SSIS package in SSDT. Or , use "Import and Export Data" tool if it's just basic import.

Comment: It is not a basic import. I need it to work from my java code.

Comment: Then try with SSIS package in SSDT. It have JDBC connectors.